# cannot download images from server to blackberry simulator using phonegap

Tags: cordova, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I cannot get images to download from server to blackberry device
I get images of 0kb size

do I need to add some feature or permissions?

and, do we need to whitelist url like android for images to download?
here is code

```
function downloadFile(dcim, img_arr, index) {
alert("download called");
alert("value of index is" + index);

if (index == img_arr.length) {
    displayImageGallery(dcim);
    return;
}

var image_url = img_arr[index]['image_url'];
alert("the image url is" + image_url);

var localFileName = image_url.substring(image_url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

dcim.getFile(localFileName, {
    create : true,
    exclusive : false
},
        function(fileEntry) {
            var localPath = fileEntry.fullPath;
            if (device.platform === "Android"
                    && localPath.indexOf("file://") === 0) {
                localPath = localPath.substring(7);
            }
            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.download(image_url, localPath, function(entry) {
                downloadFile(dcim, img_arr, index + 1);
            }, function() {
                alert("Error While Downloading File");
            });
        }, fail);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You white list external domains by editing the config.xml file and creating access elements for each external domain need to connect with.

Here's an example:

```
<access subdomains="true" uri="http://twitter.com" />
<access subdomains="true" uri="http://myimagedomain.com" />
```

The documentation about this access element can be found here:
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/access_element_834677_11.html

Hope that helps.